# How to ger processor number from program. Linux fortran

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, openmp

I use OMP in my small program. A need to know how threads are located between processors. So how can I do it from the program?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OpenMP, but processors (both sockets and cores) only tend to have thread _affinity_ rather than strict assignment - and process threads can move between physical execution cores in a way that might make the information you're after meaningless. Can you please explain what you're ultimate objective is?

Comment: @Dai, we have environment variables the OMP_PROC_BIND and the OMP_PLACES which control the thread affinity policy and whether OpenMP threads can be moved between places.